# Using powershell to return folder permissions

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and trying to use this script that I found to return folder permissions:

```
Function Get-SecGroups($path) 
{ 
  $a = @{};
  get-acl -Path $path | %{Write-Host `n $path; $_.Access} | %{
    #ONLY SHOW PERMISSIONS ON FOLDER, NOT FILES 
    #CHECK TO SEE IF THE USER/GROUP ONLY HAS "List" PERMISSION 
    if ($_.InheritanceFlags -eq "ContainerInherit") 
    { 
      Write-Host `t $_.IdentityReference "List";
    }
    else 
    { 
      Write-Host `t $_.IdentityReference, $_.FileSystemRights; 
    } 
  } 
} 
#END Get-SecGroups

get-childitem -Path "d:\*\*\" | where {$_.PsIsContainer} | %{Get-SecGroups($_.FullName)} | out-file c:\output.txt
```

The problem I have is that it creates the output.txt but with no data. The data is displayed on screen. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juste replace write-host by write-output in your function.

Comment: Thanks for that. That now writes the permissions to the file, but doesn't write what folder it is for.

Comment: Add `write-output $path` inside the function. Can you put ir as answered please.